# How to get just the image name from string that may have one or more images in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have to get the name of the image from the string I have in message. I have to types of strings:

> s1 = "bla bla name1.jpg bla bla name2.jpg bla bla"

and

> s2 = "bla bla name1.jpg bla bla"

and I have 2 problems:

for a function like:

```
function getPhotoName(message){
            var photoRegex = /.* (.*jpe?g).*/i; // the extension may be jpg, jpeg, JPG and JPEG
            return message.replace(photoRegex, "$1");
        }
```

it returns the name correct for the `s2` case and for the `s1` case the result is the second name.

For a function of type:

```
function getPhotoName(message){
            var photoRegex = /.* (.*jpe?g).* (.*jpe?g).*/i; // the extension may be jpg, jpeg, JPG and JPEG
            return message.replace(photoRegex, "$1");
        }
```

the result are ok for the `s1` case, but for the `s2` case, the result is the name and the text before it (`"bla bla name1.jpg"`).

How to make this work?

Comment: Do you have control of the string output? it may make things easier (although you might like regex :)) by just introducing a seperator such as a comma and then just split the string based on that

Comment: I control the result of the getPhotoName, but I do not control message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `match()`:

```
var names = "bla bla name1.jpg bla bla name2.jpg bla bla".match(/(\w+\.jpe?g)/gi) //["name1.jpg", "name2.jpg"]
var names = "bla bla name1.jpg bla bla".match(/(\w+\.jpe?g)/gi)// ["name1.jpg"]
var names = "bla bla image.JPEG bla bla".match(/(\w+\.jpe?g)/gi)// ["image.JPEG"]
```

Answer (score 1):

The below code  will satisfy both 2 conditions.

```
var str ="bla bla name1.jpg bla bla"

var arr = str.split(" ")

var obj = arr.filter(function(elem){  if(elem.indexOf(".")>-1) return true; })
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your filenames do not have spaces in it, I think you can do it with one regular expression for file extension only:

```
function getFileNames(str) {
   return str.split(' ').filter(function(candidate) {
      return !!candidate.match(/\.jpe?g$/i);
   });
};
```

This will return an array with file names.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in your regex. Missing the `g` flag to get all matches.

```
var jpegNames = /(\S+\.jpe?g)/gi
s1.match(jpegNames)
s2.match(jpegNames)
```

Though that won't work if there are spaces in the names.
If you really want the names together in the same string, you can `join(" ")` the resulting array.